# google fit history API

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-fit

I'm trying to use Google Fit History API to get details about my steps, calories and distance that has been recorded into my account. So I can generate a list that contains days and amount recorded for that date. However, it seems like that it doesn't really go back in date and I seem to struggle to put those details in the list. The code below only shows what I've done for calories but steps and distance follows the same principle. I have also registered my Client with OAUTH id too.

```
private float showCalories(DataReadResult dataReadResult) {
    List<DailyCalories> mCaloriesList = new ArrayList<>();
    float calories = 0;
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
    Log.i(TAG, "Range Start: " + dateFormat.format(startWeek));
    Log.i(TAG, "Range End: " + dateFormat.format(endWeek));

    Bucket bucket = dataReadResult.getBuckets().get(0);
    List<DataSet> dataSets = bucket.getDataSets();
    for (DataSet dataSet : dataSets) {
        for (DataPoint dataPoint : dataSet.getDataPoints()) {
            Log.i("TAG","Type : " + dataPoint.getDataType().getName());
            Log.i("TAG", "StartTime : " + dateFormat.format(dataPoint.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
            Log.i("TAG", "EndTime : " + dateFormat.format(dataPoint.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
            for (Field field : dataPoint.getDataType().getFields()) {
                calories = dataPoint.getValue(field).asFloat();
                Log.i("TAG" , "Field : " + field.getName() + "Value : " + dataPoint.getValue(field));
                //mCaloriesList.add(calories, dataPoint.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
            }
        }
    }
    return (int) calories;
}



private void setWeekTime() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date now = new Date();
    calendar.setTime(now);
    endWeek = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    calendar.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -2);
    startWeek = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
}

private DataReadRequest queryFitnessDataWeekly(DataType mDataType, DataType nDataType) {
    return new DataReadRequest.Builder()
        .aggregate(mDataType, nDataType)
        .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
        .setTimeRange(startWeek, endWeek, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .build();
}

private void caloriesCountWeekly() {
    DataReadRequest readCaloriesDataWeekly = queryFitnessDataWeekly(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED, DataType.AGGREGATE_CALORIES_EXPENDED);
    Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(mClient, readCaloriesDataWeekly).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataReadResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull DataReadResult dataReadResult) {
            //showCaloriesForLastWeek(dataReadResult);
            //wListener.onLastWeekCaloriesUpdated(showCalories(dataReadResult));
            showCalories(dataReadResult);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is your error log?

Comment: Did you get this issue resolved? Even I am trying to do the same thing.